# Sniffing received HTTP post packets with python

Tags: python, http, post, packet

I am trying to **manage** some **HTTP Post requests** being ***received on my computer.*** The post requests are from an apache server ***(website) which is being hosted on the same computer***. How can I manage them using ***python***, *preferably without using any 3rd party modules*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is very lightweight and does not require many things, you can use the built-in socket module and create a server yourself (https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html). If it requires things like security then Flask or Django would be a good choice (https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/) (https://www.djangoproject.com/).

Comment: I have tried the socket module and have tried binding it to the port on which my webserver is being hosted, but it gives me an error saying the address is already in use.

Comment: it does not need to be on the same port to receive data. localhost is localhost. You can bind the python script to any port that is valid and itll be able to recv data

Comment: I did it says 'Transport endpoint not connected' 